# select all column of table but row should be filtered by unique or disticnt entry in a column

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `history` (
`bill_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `cid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`pid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`TIME` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`price` decimal(65,4) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `history`

```
INSERT INTO `history` (`cid`, `pid`, `TIME`, `price`) VALUES
(3, 1, '2014-11-12 17:39:14', '71500.0000'),
(3, 3, '2014-11-12 17:39:14', '22500.0000'),
(3, 1, '2014-11-12 17:40:36', '71500.0000'),
(3, 1, '2014-11-12 17:52:36', '71500.0000'),
(3, 3, '2014-11-12 19:09:23', '22500.0000'),
(3, 5, '2014-11-12 19:09:23', '29000.0000'),
(3, 9, '2014-11-12 19:09:23', '29000.0000');
```

I WANT A QUERY WHICH SHOULD GIVE THE FOLLOWING OUTPUT on the basis of cid but unique/distinct TIME

PRINTING UNIQUE/DISTINCT VALUE

```
  (3, '2014-11-12 17:39:14')
  (3, '2014-11-12 17:40:36')
  (3, '2014-11-12 17:52:36')
  (3, '2014-11-12 19:09:23')
  (3, '2014-11-12 19:09:23')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you try with a simple sub query like

```
select * from history where `time` in (select distinct `time` from history);
```